# How to use angular to handle page navigation in single-page application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a single-page app that updates divs on the page by calling the server via ajax. I am using angular as the framework.

I am trying to handle page navigation through angular but I'm struggling a bit to understand it.

I've been looking at the $route functionality, and in the examples I've seen, you specify a template to be loaded. But I don't want to do that. What I would like to happen is this:

when the location url changes, eg from /#page1 to /#page2, a function in my controller gets called that can make the ajax call and update the appropriate div.

I would also like this to happen if the user manually changes the url in the browser address bar, and I would also like the app to load the correct page if a user comes straight to /#page1 or /#page2 eg from an outside link.

Is that the kind of thing I could use angular routes to do and is it the best tool for the job?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: AngularJS's templates are like the ajax call you described, but they only ever update a single div, otherwise you need to look at the `ng-include` directive. Also do the [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00) to learn about routing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll bite the bullet and do the tutorial..

Comment: As you are talking about ajax I would really suggest it. Regarding redirecting the user to this url, that all depends on how your server sends the page initially.